# Removing non-Latin characters from a string

Tags: javascript, unicode

I'm trying to remove non-Latin characters from a string with Javascript. I'm using the following code:

```
text.replace(/[\u0250-\ue007f]/g, '')
```

I first thought it was working fine, until I discovered it also removes the 'f' character from the string. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try this:-

```
 text.replace(/[\u0250-\ue007]/g, '');
```

Comment: Since I can't accept my own answer for 2 days, I'll take this one :)

Answer (score 5):

Oops, I must be tired. After posting and looking at it, I discovered the 'f' at the end of the expression...

So it should be

```
text.replace(/[\u0250-\ue007]/g, '')
```